# php comparing timestamps within an hour +/-

Tags: php

I have a conditional written that compares two timestamps and I need it to execute if the time difference between the control variable and the compared variable is within 1 hour plus or minus of the compared.

it looks like this right now which is obviously only less than & equal to:

```
if( ($departure - $item['time']) <= 3600) ):
```

would changing `<=` to `<=>` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `<=>` operator will offer combined comparison in that it will :

```
Return 0 if values on either side are equal
Return 1 if value on the left is greater
Return -1 if the value on the right is greater
```

What you want to do instead is to compare the [absolute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) value of `$departure - $item['time']`

```
if(abs($departure - $item['time']) <= 3600)):
```

Comment: simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

No, the `<=>` operator just returns a -1/0/1 when one side is smaller/equal/larger respectively, and it only works in PHP7.

It actually seems that in your case `$departure - $item['time']` could go into negative values (if `$item['time']` is larger than `$departure`) and so your if statement will evaluate to true in cases when, say, `$item['time']` is two, three or more hours in the future from `$departure`.

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
$diff = $departure - $item['time'];
if ($diff <= 3600 && $diff >= -3600)
{
    // do what you have to do
}
```

`&&` (AND) is a logical operator which means that both smaller statements must evaluate to true, in order for the complete statement to be true.

Comment: yes that appears to work, thank you so much. sometimes it just takes a different set of eyes to look at it for a solution!